# Firebase StreamSubscription not getting data in flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 StreamSubscriptions that I want to use to get data from Firebase documents.

The first one is _trxnStream, the second is _clientStream.

When I try to use these StreamSubscriptions the _trxnStream works fine. I am able to get data from the trxns document but _clientStream does not pull data from the document.

```
final clientFNameController = TextEditingController();


late final StreamSubscription _trxnStream;
late final StreamSubscription _clientStream;
    
  getTrxn() async {
    //if (widget.trxns == null) {
    if (widget.newTrxn!) {
      _companyId = ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId;
      //_selectedCompany = _companyId;
      //ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewTrxn(false);

      // new record: Set the textFields to blank
      clientFNameController.text = "";
      clientLNameController.text = "";
      clientAddress1Controller.text = "";
      clientAddress2Controller.text = "";
      clientCityController.text = "";
      clientStateController.text = "";
      clientTypeController.text = "";
      clientCellPhoneController.text = "";
      clientHomePhoneController.text = "";
      clientEmailController.text = "";

      propertyAddressController.text = "";
      propertyCityController.text = "";
      propertyStateController.text = "";
      propertyZipcodeController.text = "";
      mlsNumberController.text = "";
      contractDateController.text = "";
      contractPriceController.text = "";
      sellerDisclosure24aController.text = "";
      dueDiligence24bController.text = "";
      financing2cController.text = "";
      settlement24dController.text = "";
      inspectorCompanyController.text = "";
      inspectorPhoneController.text = "";
      inspectionDateController.text = "";
      appraiserController.text = "";
      appraiserPhoneController.text = "";
      appraisalDateController.text = "";
      closingDateController.text = "";
      walkThroughDateController.text = "";
      titleCompanyController.text = "";
      titlePhoneController.text = "";
      titleEmailController.text = "";
      mortgageCompanyController.text = "";
      mortgagePhoneController.text = "";
      mortgageEmailController.text = "";
      otherAgentController.text = "";
      otherAgentEmailController.text = "";
      otherAgentPhoneController.text = "";
      otherPartyClientController.text = "";
      otherPartyTitleCompanyController.text = "";
      trxnStatusController.text = "";
      trxnIdController.text = "";
      setState(() {
        _trxnStatus = 'Select Status';
      });
    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot _mlsId =
          await mlsRef.doc(ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).mlsId).get();
      _mlsSearchLink = _mlsId.get('mlsNbrSearch');

      try {
        _trxnStream = _db
            .collection('company')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
            .collection('trxns')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentTrxnId)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((trxnSnapshot) {
          clientTypeController.text = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? "";
          _clientType = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? "";

          _clientId = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientId'] ?? "";

          _clientType =
              trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? 'Select Client Type';
          _selectedCompany = trxnSnapshot.data()?['companyId'] ?? "";
          _selectedUser = trxnSnapshot.data()?['userId'] ?? "";
          _selectedClientState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientState'] ?? "";
          if (trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'] == null ||
              trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'] == "") {
            _currentState = "AL";
          } else {
            _currentState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'];
          }
          // });

          try {
            _clientStream = _db
                .collection('client')
                .doc(_clientId)
                .snapshots()
                .listen((clientSnapshot) {
              clientFNameController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientFName'] ?? "";
              clientLNameController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientLName'] ?? "";
              clientAddress1Controller.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientAddress1'] ?? "";
              clientAddress2Controller.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientAddress2'] ?? "";
              clientCityController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientCity'] ?? "";
              clientStateController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientState'] ?? "";
              clientCellPhoneController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientCellPhone'] ?? "";
              clientCellPhoneController.text != "" &&
                      clientCellPhoneController.text != null
                  ? _hasCellNumber = true
                  : _hasCellNumber = false;
              _clientCellPhoneNumber =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientCellPhone'] ?? "";
              clientHomePhoneController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientHomePhone'] ?? "";
              clientHomePhoneController.text != "" &&
                      clientHomePhoneController.text != null
                  ? _hasHomeNumber = true
                  : _hasHomeNumber = false;
              _clientHomePhoneNumber =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientHomePhone'] ?? "";
              clientEmailController.text =
                  clientSnapshot.data()?['clientEmail'] ?? "";
            });
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Why am I not able to get the data from the client document? _clientId has the correct value to link to the correct client document.

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE:**
I added the method getTrxn where I am getting the data. Also, I added where I am declaring clientFNameController.

Please let me know if you need more. This class is quite large so I don't want to put the whole thing in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you named the JSON field correctly?

it says `['clientFName']` maybe it's a typo and you meant `['clientName']`

if that's not the issue does it throw an error or just gives you and empty string?

Comment: Yes, clientFName is correct and there is no error thrown. Thanks for your response.

Comment: can I see the rest of the code? where the clientFNameController is defined and used

Comment: I added more code to the original post.